# How can i stop a running procees with multithreading in python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, discord.py

I made a Discord-Bot to control my fairy lights and wanted to include a party function.
I want the party function to stop when chatting *!p stop* and to start when chatting *!p start*. This is what I tried:

```
import multiprocessing

import time
import RGB as rgb
import discord
import random

dc = discord.Client()

rot = 1
grün = 2
blau = 3

#Following is because of RGB toggeling
global statr
global statg
global statb
statr = "aus"
statg = "aus"
statb = "aus"
#Ok toggeling stopped

global statP
statP = 1

def party():
    rgb.start()
    while statP != 0:
        anAus = random.randint(1, 2)
        faabe = random.randint(1, 4)
        if anAus == 1:
            rgb.on(faabe)
        if anAus == 2:
            rgb.off(faabe)
#        dur = dur - 1
        time.sleep(random.uniform(0.02, 0.07))

global proc
proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=party, args=())

@dc.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id == dc.user.id:
        return
    if message.content.startswith("!p start"):
        #msg = message.content
        #rest = msg.replace("!party ", "")
        #msg = "Mache " + rest + " Durchläufe lang Party."
        #await message.channel.send(msg)
#        Thread(target = party).start()
        statP = 1
        proc.start()
    if message.content.startswith("!p stop"):
        statP = 0
```

How can i make that? I tried some other ways from here and googled about 2h long and couldnt find anything that worked for me.

Comment: Multiprocessing does not share variables. Try using threading instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't do this with multiprocessing, I'd just run the whole thing in one thread (thats what asyncio is made for) like this:

```
import time
import RGB as rgb
import discord
import random
import asyncio

dc = discord.Client()

rot = 1
grün = 2
blau = 3

statr = "aus"
statg = "aus"
statb = "aus"

statP = 1

async def party():
    rgb.start()
    while True:
        if statP != 0:
            anAus = random.randint(1, 2)
            faabe = random.randint(1, 4)
            if anAus == 1:
                rgb.on(faabe)
            if anAus == 2:
                rgb.off(faabe)
            #        dur = dur - 1
        await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(0.02, 0.07))


@dc.event
async def on_message(message):
    global statP
    if message.author.id == dc.user.id:
        return
    if message.content.startswith("!p start"):
        message.channel.send('started the party')
        statP = 1
    if message.content.startswith("!p stop"):
        statP = 0

dc.loop.create_task(party())

dc.run(TOKEN)
```

note1: I have no clue how your RGB library is supposed to work

note2: I don't know german so might have missed some of your intended use of functionality

The way this works is that you let your party function slumber with `await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(***))` instead of blocking the thread with sleep. While it slumbers it gives the opportunity to your program to get new messages and react to them. Before running the bot the `party`function is added to the loop, and it'll run for ever because of the `while True` loop

Comment: I made myself an api for making my code easyer to understand

Comment: I made something like this for a rainbow loop now but it is stuck at the first color. I just took the same thing and into the if i just put:
```Python
rgb.red(1)
asyncio.sleep(0.2)
rgb.green(1)
asyncio.sleep(0.2)
rgb.red(0)
asyncio.sleep(0.2)
```

Comment: Without seeing your code or understanding how exactly you control the leds i cant really say whats wrong, the snippet you sent should work, but i cant see the indentation you used or the surrounding code

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
import threading

import time
import RGB as rgb
import discord
import random

dc = discord.Client()

rot = 1
grün = 2
blau = 3

global statr
global statg
global statb
statr = "aus"
statg = "aus"
statb = "aus"

global statP
statP = 1

def party():
    rgb.start()
    while statP != 0:
        anAus = random.randint(1, 2)
        faabe = random.randint(1, 4)
        if anAus == 1:
            rgb.on(faabe)
        if anAus == 2:
            rgb.off(faabe)
#        dur = dur - 1
        time.sleep(random.uniform(0.02, 0.07))

#global proc
#proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=party, args=())

@dc.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id == dc.user.id:
        return
    if message.content.startswith("!p start"):
        #msg = message.content
        #rest = msg.replace("!party ", "")
        #msg = "Mache " + rest + " Durchläufe lang Party."
        #await message.channel.send(msg)
        statP = 1
        threading.Thread(target = party).start()
#        proc.start()
    if message.content.startswith("!p stop"):
        statP = 0
```